# How to get post back url from on ajax:success

Tags: jquery

On the server when doing a post it redirects to a new url with the created object. 
How can I get that url from this request?

```
$(".trend-item .trend-form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  return my_function();
});
```

I need to query that created url that contains and ID so I can hook that up on the response.

Comment: I currently get the html response of the whole page on the ajax call. I just need to get the url of that.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the contents of ``xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()``

Comment: I see a `X-Xhr-Redirected-To: ` the url I need. How can I query that?

Comment: @sqren already told you how to read the header.

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching the `X-Xhr-Redirected-To:` from `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`:

```
/**
 * XmlHttpRequest's getAllResponseHeaders() method returns a string of response
 * headers according to the format described here:
 * http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders-method
 * This method parses that string into a user-friendly key/value pair object.
 */
function parseResponseHeaders(headerStr) {
  var headers = {};
  if (!headerStr) {
    return headers;
  }
  var headerPairs = headerStr.split('\u000d\u000a');
  for (var i = 0; i < headerPairs.length; i++) {
    var headerPair = headerPairs[i];
    // Can't use split() here because it does the wrong thing
    // if the header value has the string ": " in it.
    var index = headerPair.indexOf('\u003a\u0020');
    if (index > 0) {
      var key = headerPair.substring(0, index);
      var val = headerPair.substring(index + 2);
      headers[key] = val;
    }
  }
  return headers;
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/monsur/706839)